# How to append <cr> to a register from a yank?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, register

I am actually stuck level 10 at [vim-adventures](http://vim-adventures.com), but this question concerns vim in general.

I have a new file with this content:

```
99 bottles of beer
```

If I yank the line with <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> I get `99 bottles of beer<cr>`, if I do <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>$</kbd> I get `99 bottles of beer` without the new line.

The question is how can I just append `<cr>` that I yank from somewhere into my registers?

Comment: If you can do `"aY`why don't you use it?

Comment: Because `"aY` will yank the whole line. I just need to yank the `<cr>` to append it to another register.

Comment: "will yank the whole line" - and that's exactly what you wanted!

Comment: Related: `:put a` will do a linewise put of register a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a capital "A" for the yank command which appends to the register instead of replacing it. So you would need to position your cursor on a blank line and then do `"AY`.

See `:h quote` for more info.

Another way to do it would be to run the following command:

```
:let @a = @a . "\n"
```

Registers can be address like variables with @ notation.

Comment: So you need a bank line. That what I need to find then.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the `setreg()` function:

```
:call setreg('a', "\n", 'a')
```

With the help of [`:h setreg()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#setreg()):

- The first parameter is the name of the register to modify
- The second one is the string to put into the register
- The third one is optional, if it contains `a` then the string is appended to the content of the register otherwise it replace the existing content.

Answer (score 1):

There is `setreg()` method, you can not only modify the value of the register, but also the "mode" see `:h setreg(`.

you can just convert the char-based selection/yank to line-based selection/yank, without changing the value of `@a`:

```
:call setreg('a',@a,'V')
```

or

```
:call setreg('a',@a,'l')
```